# How load extra plugins for Zend Dojo Form Element Editor?

Tags: zend-form, dojo, zend-framework

I have simple Zend_Dojo_Form with Editor element, when I add aditional plugins I got notice from firebug

```
Cannot find plugin linkdialog
```

the code

```
class Some_Form extends Zend_Dojo_Form
{
    public function init() {
        $this->addElement('Editor', 'content', array(
            'label'=> 'Some editor title',

            'dijitParams' => array(
                'extraPlugins'=>array('linkdialog')
             ),
        );
    }
 }
```

How I can enable aditional plugins for Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_Editor? I tried to include manualy, but same results.

```
dojo.require("dijit._editor.plugins.LinkDialog");
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Alan Kay, you got me on the right track, but to elaborate a little more.

There seems to be two categories of Dojo editor plugins, '**(built-in) plugins**' and '**extraPlugins**'.

Here's a list of [built-in plugins](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Editor.html#builtin-commands) (unsure if it's up-to-date). You can add built-in plugins on Dojo enabled Zend Forms Elements fine:

```php
$this->addElement('editor', 'summary', array(
    'label'              => 'Summary:',
    'plugins'            => array(
        // NOTE: specifying any will lose the default builtin plugins, 
        // so need to re-add the ones you want.
        // Builtin plugins
        'bold', 'italic', 'underline', '|',
        'insertOrderedList', 'insertUnorderedList', '|',
        'indent', 'outdent', '|',
        'justifyLeft', 'justifyRight', 'justifyCenter', 'justifyFull', '|',
        // dijit._editor.plugins that work
        'foreColor', 'hiliteColor', '|',            // TextColor
        'fontName', 'fontSize', 'formatBlock', '|', // FontChoice
        'createLink', 'insertImage', '|',           // LinkDialog
        'viewSource',                               // ViewSource
    )
));
```

Alternatively, there are two main libraries of extraPlugins, Dijit (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/_editor/plugins.html#dijit-editor-plugins) and Dojox (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/editor/plugins.html#dojox-editor-plugins). Unfortunately, 'extraPlugins' are unavailable in Zend Framework until the next minor release (1.12) [ZF-11511](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11511). You could use the patch to create your own library to extend Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_Editor in the meantime.

Note, when specifying 'extraPlugins', you want to use the 'short name' (e.g. 'createLink'), not the 'resource' (e.g. 'linkdialog'):

> "The bolded text represents the resource; the basic text represents the
>   "short name" to be added to the extraPlugins list." *'Using Plugins' (http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/editor/)*

However, note in the above example, it's possible to include the 'short names' for **some** Dijit extraPlugin 'resources', but not Dojox to my knowledge. Unsure why this is (haven't looked into dojo src - anyone?). Try your luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for your exact syntax, but you don't want to set 'LinkDialog', you want 'createLink'. I'm guessing `'extraPlugins'=>array('createLink')` is the change you need

I know the following works for me:

```
$this->addElement(new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_Editor('content',
    array(
        'label' => 'Content:',
        'class' => 'soria',
        )
    )
);
$this->contents->addPlugins(array('|', 'createLink');
```